# sqlplus command not found zabbix

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, zabbix

I'm working and discovering the world of Zabbix. In particular I am trying to monitor an Oracle database with the Zabbix server through an external script. Given that other external scripts work, however, I created one with sqlplus, but on Zabbix I get "command not found". Can you tell me why?
The code is:

```
check.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $out=`echo "select * from v$version;" | sqlplus user/password@ip_database:port`;
print $out;
```

The code is very simple.
I created an item as always, passed as type "external check" and a key I entered my script. Can anyone solve my problem? Also if I was not clear, just ask for more information rather than "insult" on the forum: Thanks to everyone in advance

I RESOLVED IT WITH:

```
echo "/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib" >> /etc/profile
```

THANKS TO ALL!!!!

Comment: Is the machine on which your executing this script is linux or windows? If Linux then did you installed Oracle client/SQL client on it?

Comment: @Ankit Hi, the machine is Linux. Oracle client/SQL client is installed on. If try the code on terminal it works, but when I insert it on Zabbix, I get "command not found". Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your zabbix server does not have the necessary environment to find `sqlplus`. You could simply use the full path to `sqlplus` in your script (but that alone might not be enough) or create a wrapper script that sets all the necessary environment variables for your script.

From TFM:

> The command will be executed as the user Zabbix server runs as, so any
>   access permissions or environment variables should be handled in a
>   wrapper script, if necessary, and permissions on the command should
>   allow that user to execute it.

Comment: Hi, I think too that the problem is permission but I don't how to set it. Can you help me?

Comment: In a linux console window, type this: `which sqlplus`. The output could be something like `/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/bin/sqlplus`. In your script, replace `sqlplus` with the output of the `which` command, e.g. `my $out='echo "select * from v$version;" | /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/bin/sqlplus user/password@ip_database:port';` (beware that I had to change the backticks in your script, because this site uses them for formatting)

Comment: I try it and this is my new error: /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/bin/sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: To make it work, you need several environment variables set to appropriate values: `ORACLE_HOME`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and maybe more.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to configure the sqlplus libraries required to run sqlplus. The script which you use to start the zabbix server you can configure below oracle things in the startup script so that zabbix can find all necessary libraries to run.

> export ORACLE_HOME={path to Oracle Client}
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${ORACLE_HOME}/lib

If still there are issues related to .so files then there must be some issues in your SQL client installation.

Comment: To start zabbix server I use systemctl start zabbix-server. So this configuration I must insert into script perl?

Comment: Yes. But the syntax to declare above variables may be different in Perl since I don't have much knowledge about perl. :)

Comment: where can I find the path to oracle client?

Comment: As mentioned in below comment I guess this will be your Oracle client path "/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0"